# Javascript remove text from a class

Tags: javascript, string, class, text

I need to remove the text 'at' from this title.

```
<p><a href="/pankcake" class="spotlight__title">Marge Makes Pancakes Email at</a></p>
```

The text in this title is dynamically created so I can't change the whole thing.
I tried using this but it doesn't work.

```
<script>var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("spotlight__title");elements[0].innerHTML=elements[0].innerHTML.replace(/at/g,"");</script>
```

Comment: Okay so I put that in the footer and it worked. But I have multiple instances of this class and it's only removed it off of the first one.

Comment: Can you use JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over collection returned from **getElementsByClassName**.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("spotlight__title");
Array.from(elements).forEach( element =>
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/at/g,"")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to find all elements by using a CSS Selector and then iterate over them to replace text according to your regex.

```js
function replaceText(target, re, newText) {
  document.querySelectorAll(target).forEach(function(element) {
    element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(re, newText).trim();
  });
}

replaceText('.spotlight__title', /at$/g, '');
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="/pankcake" class="spotlight__title">Marge Makes Pancakes Email 1 at</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="/pankcake" class="spotlight__title">Marge Makes Pancakes Email 2 at</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="/pankcake" class="spotlight__title">Marge Makes Pancakes Email 3 at</a>
</p>
```